# Download more than Approx 2.5 GB is not working in IE 11

Tags: java, struts2, zip, internet-explorer-11

I am working on one Java(Struts2) based web application, there is one functionality for zip download, which allows end user to select some documents from list and allow to download as zip(containing selected documents). On server side I do get this list and write zip stream in the response.

Now this zip file is getting downloaded in chrome, FF but not downloaded in IE11, there is no server side error also.

After some time it shows 'This download was interrupted.' with resume and cancel button.

I am stuck with this from last week, cant find any solution.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/03/10/wininet-internet-explorer-file-download-and-upload-maximum-size-limits.aspx.

Comment: Are you running different IE11 from different PCs, or just tried with once ? Do you have any plugin, download manager, special settings etc... on IE11 ? Is it run from the same machine from where you downloaded the zip with FF e Chrome ? Can you try disabling antiviruses, firewalls etc on your client ?

Comment: Show how do you write zip stream into the response.

Comment: @AndreaLigios, I tried with different machines, in other machines works perfectly. I am not using any plugin. The application deployed on different machine than the IE11 machine(with Chrome and FF). The failures are also with 50/50 ratio, some times it works also.

Comment: It must be Skynet taking over...